# Displaying a view path inside it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there any way I can access a view path (for instance "~/Views/Order/OrderResult.cshtml") in the view itself in ASP.MVC 4?

Comment: Try using partial rendering

Comment: Could you explain your idea? - because I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MVC, this can be achieved using:

```
((RazorView)ViewContext.View).ViewPath
```